# Fetch data from 3 tables in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join

I need to fetch all the rows from 3 tables that have `name="some string"`.

- `table1` has some rows with `name="testing123"`
- `table2` has some rows with `name="testing456"`
- `table3` has some rows with `name="testing789"`

So my query should return 3 rows that match `name="testing%"`.

I tried `inner join`, but it doesn't return any:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
    ON table1.name$ = table2.name$
INNER JOIN table3
    ON table1.name$ = table3.name$
    WHERE obj_cd3a93e8.name$ LIKE 'testing%';
```

Comment: You probably need to use UNION or UNION ALL

Comment: What's wrong with your current query??  What's your expected output?

Comment: Is the structure of the all the three tables same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you probably want to use a union instead:

```
select column
from table1
where $name like 'some string'
Union
select column
from table2
where $name like 'some string'
Union 
select column
from table3
where $name like 'some string'
```

Answer (score 0):

If your tables have same structure then use union as mentioned by @Sebastien.

Else if want all the columns of the three tables to be selected and there is no common columns in all the three tables. Use a catesian product :

```
select 
* 
from table1 t1 ,
     table2 t2,
     table3 t3
where t1.name = 'testing123'
and t2.name = 'testing456'
and t3.name = 'testing789';
```

Comment: As you have mentioned about @Sebastien fix, yes i have the same structure so it works!!!

Comment: Good to know :)